# How to pass in function's argument a pointer function using wrapper function?

Tags: c, pthreads, wrapper

I have this function:

```
void boot(uint ncores, uint nterm, Task boot_task, int argl, void* args)
{

 for(int i=0; i<MAX_PROC;i++) {
    PT[i].ppid = NOPROC;
 }
 nextproc = 0;

 curproc = NOPROC;
 Exec(boot_task, argl, args);
}
```

and and I want instead of using `Exec()` to use `pthread`, so I have to call the cpu_boot:

```
void cpu_boot(uint cores, interrupt_handler bootfunc, uint serialno)
{
 //I cannot change this function 
}
```

These are the types of the arguments

```
typedef void interrupt_handler();
typedef int (* Task)(int, void*);
```

I've tried:

```
void boot(uint ncores, uint nterm, Task boot_task, int argl, void* args)
{
    void my_wrapper()
    {

        int y;
        y= boot_task(argl, args);
    }

    cpu_boot(ncores, my_wrapper , nterm);
}
```

But this is wrong. How can I implement this?

Comment: since the two variables: PT[] and nextproc are not defined (are they global variables?)   there are a few other problems: 1) cannot next functions in C 2) the typedef statements need a 'trailing' name to use to reference the typedef.  3) this: typedef void interrupt_handler(); is not a valid prototype for an interrupt function.  this is: typedef void interrupt_handler(void); as interrupt functions cannot have passed in parameters, as they are never called.

Comment: @user3629249: The two typedefs are 'OK'; the names of the typedefs are `interrupt_handler` and `Task`.  The definition of `interrupt_handler` should specify the acceptable arguments, or specify `void` if the function takes no arguments, but that is a (relatively) minor issue.  Note that standard signal handlers in user-space, where pthreads are normally used, have the type `void (*handler)(int signum);` -- the function takes an argument.  Signal handlers and interrupt handlers are called; they'd be pointless if they were never called.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want something like this:

```
void some_interrupt_handler(){
    /* code here */
    return;
}

interrupt_handler* my_wrapper(Task boot_task, int argl, void* args)
{
    /* 
      this is where you run boot task
    */
    boot_task(argl, args);

    /* then pick an interrupt_handler to return... */
    void (*function_ptr)() = some_interrupt_handler;

    return function_ptr;
}
```

Then you can use your wrapper like this:

```
void boot(uint ncores, uint nterm, Task boot_task, int argl, void* args)
{
    cpu_boot(ncores, my_wrapper(boot_task, argl, args) , nterm);
}
```

Comment: How can I pass in the argument bootfunc the label of a wrapper function without calling it?? Something like that cpu_boot(ncores, my_wrapper , nterm); @Grzegorz Szpetkowski

Comment: @Lefteris Sarantaris: you could pass the function pointer as yet another parameter of my_wrapper. You can't do `cpu_boot(ncores,my_wrapper, nterm)` unless `my_wrapper` is of type interrupt_handler - in which case you won't have the option of passing any arguments (argl,args etc) to it because interrupt_handler does not take arguments... I think the closest you can get is `my_wrapper(boot_task,boot_func,argl,args)` where boot_func is a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

A more generic and much more flexable way...

```
void some_interrupt_handler(){
    /* code here */
    return;
}

typdef struct boot_data_struct {
    int argc;
    void * argv;
    Task boot_task;
    interrupt_handler * handler;
} boot_data;

interrupt_handler* my_wrapper(void * data)
{
    boot_data * bootData = data;

    /* 
      this is where you run boot task
    */
    data->boot_task(bootData->argc, bootData->argv);

    return bootData->handler;
}
```

Then you can use your wrapper like this:

```
void boot(uint ncores, uint nterm, Task boot_task, int argl, void* args)
{
    boot_data * data = malloc(sizeof *data); 
    //remember to memset if you arent going to fill out all variables!
    data->argc = argl;
    data->argv = args;
    data->boot_task = boot_task;
    data->handler = some_interrupt_handler;

    cpu_boot(ncores, my_wrapper(data) , nterm);

    free(data);
}
```